# Best setup variables for mysql with big large table row size?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Here are the variables for our server, and I want to know what are the best settings for mysql server with 2.5 million records transaction...

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'innodb%';
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                               | Value                  |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                    | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm                | 10.000000              |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index                  | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions       | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts            | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay             | 150000                 |
| innodb_autoextend_increment                 | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                    | 1                      |
| innodb_background_scrub_data_check_interval | 3600                   |
| innodb_background_scrub_data_compressed     | OFF                    |
| innodb_background_scrub_data_interval       | 604800                 |
| innodb_background_scrub_data_uncompressed   | OFF                    |
| innodb_buf_dump_status_frequency            | 0                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size               | 134217728              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown         | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct                 | 25                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename                 | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances                | 8                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort               | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup          | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                     | 12884901888            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size               | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                     | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                   | crc32                  |
| innodb_checksums                            | ON                     |
| innodb_cleaner_lsn_age_factor               | DEPRECATED             |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled                | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                   | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_algorithm                | zlib                   |
| innodb_compression_default                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct    | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                    | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max              | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets                  | 5000                   |
| innodb_corrupt_table_action                 | deprecated             |
| innodb_data_file_path                       | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                        |                        |
| innodb_deadlock_detect                      | ON                     |
| innodb_default_encryption_key_id            | 1                      |
| innodb_default_row_format                   | dynamic                |
| innodb_defragment                           | OFF                    |
| innodb_defragment_fill_factor               | 0.900000               |
| innodb_defragment_fill_factor_n_recs        | 20                     |
| innodb_defragment_frequency                 | 40                     |
| innodb_defragment_n_pages                   | 7                      |
| innodb_defragment_stats_accuracy            | 0                      |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache              | OFF                    |
| innodb_disallow_writes                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                          | ON                     |
| innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm            | DEPRECATED             |
| innodb_encrypt_log                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_encrypt_tables                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age            | 1                      |
| innodb_encryption_rotation_iops             | 100                    |
| innodb_encryption_threads                   | 0                      |
| innodb_fake_changes                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                        | 1                      |
| innodb_fatal_semaphore_wait_threshold       | 600                    |
| innodb_file_format                          | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_format_check                    | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                      | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_per_table                       | ON                     |
| innodb_fill_factor                          | 100                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout                 | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                         |                        |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                      | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_sync                           | ON                     |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_primary_key                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                       | 0                      |
| innodb_foreground_preflush                  | DEPRECATED             |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                         |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                        | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                   | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                    | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                    | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize                 | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit                | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table             |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                   | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                  | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table               |                        |
| innodb_idle_flush_pct                       | 100                    |
| innodb_immediate_scrub_data_uncompressed    | OFF                    |
| innodb_instrument_semaphores                | OFF                    |
| innodb_io_capacity                          | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                      | 2000                   |
| innodb_kill_idle_transaction                | 0                      |
| innodb_large_prefix                         | ON                     |
| innodb_lock_schedule_algorithm              | vats                   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                    | 50                     |
| innodb_locking_fake_changes                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog              | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_arch_dir                         |                        |
| innodb_log_arch_expire_sec                  | 0                      |
| innodb_log_archive                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_block_size                       | 0                      |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                      | 16777216               |
| innodb_log_checksum_algorithm               | DEPRECATED             |
| innodb_log_checksums                        | ON                     |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages                 | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                        | 3221225472             |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                   | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                   | ./                     |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                 | 8192                   |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                       | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_bitmap_file_size                 | 0                      |
| innodb_max_changed_pages                    | 0                      |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct                  | 75.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm              | 0.000000               |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                        | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay                  | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                    | 10485760               |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups                  | 0                      |
| innodb_monitor_disable                      |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                       |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                        |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                    |                        |
| innodb_mtflush_threads                      | 8                      |
| innodb_numa_interleave                      | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                       | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                      | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size            | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                           | 2000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only               | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                        | 4                      |
| innodb_page_size                            | 16384                  |
| innodb_prefix_index_cluster_optimization    | OFF                    |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                     | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency        | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                        | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold                 | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                      | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                            | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                    | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                    | 128                    |
| innodb_sched_priority_cleaner               | 0                      |
| innodb_scrub_log                            | OFF                    |
| innodb_scrub_log_speed                      | 256                    |
| innodb_show_locks_held                      | 0                      |
| innodb_show_verbose_locks                   | 0                      |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                     | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                      | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                    | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked          | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                         | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_modified_counter               | 0                      |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                     | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages        | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                   | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_traditional                    | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages         | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                          | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                           | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                      | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                      | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                          | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path                  | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                   | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                   | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                               |                        |
| innodb_track_changed_pages                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_track_redo_log_now                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_directory                       | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_logs                            | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                     | 0                      |
| innodb_use_atomic_writes                    | ON                     |
| innodb_use_fallocate                        | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_global_flush_log_at_trx_commit   | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_mtflush                          | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_native_aio                       | ON                     |
| innodb_use_stacktrace                       | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_trim                             | ON                     |
| innodb_version                              | 5.7.18                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                     | 4                      |
+---------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, please use the formatting tools at the top of your text input box for your question - it makes your questions easier to read. Your question is overly broad - it's impossible to give a setup that is optimal for any workload - if there was an `ideal` list of settings, they would be the default and there would be no option to change. Having said that, did you search for "MySQL my.cnf  optimal settings" - I found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130810/34007),you'll have to dig around! A better idea of your workload would be an idea - OLTP or OLAP. Is this "big table" part of a DW schema

Comment: How much RAM?  How big are the rows (columns, bytes, etc)?  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Please clarify "with 2.5 million records transaction" -- 2.5M rows in one transaction?  `UPDATEing`?  `INSERTing`?  `DELETEing`?  2.5M transactions?  Transactions per year?  Transactions per second?

Comment: How much RAM?  The buffer_pool implies that you have 16GB; is that correct?